# On setting up Apache and IIS to share the same IP

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, ip, share

There are two different web-apps running on two (physically) different servers on our network... one of IIS and another one on Apache - both on port 80 since two machines are accessible by different IPs on our internal network.

Now I want to expose both these services to the world. My idea is to somehow make the incoming connection redirect to the appropriate server based on user's choice of subdomain.

**Example**

xxx.domain.com maps to the IIS (Internal IP: 1.2.3.4)

yyy.domain.com maps to Apache (Internal IP: 5.6.7.8)

To the world, both these servers will **share the same public IP**.

What kind of a configuration am I looking at and how do I go about trapping the subdomain requests and redirecting to the appropriate server?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to put a reverse proxy in front of them if your edge device doesn't support virtual hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Could you direct me to some guidelines/tutorials on the net on this?

Comment: This is a link to the mod_proxy module for Apache, which is what you would use to set this up. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Also, if you are only planning on ever having two servers, you might as well just set up forwarding on the apache box instead of putting a dedicated reverse proxy in, however - actually having a reverse proxy will allow you to grow if you really don't want to get more public IPs.

Comment: Ahaa... going through the rev. proxy docs I see that this would perfectly fit my purpose. Thanks again :)